# VB6 Debug Version works fine, compiled version wont start

Tags: vb6

I compile VB6 programs on Windows 10 regularly.  I currently have a project which has worked on an old machine but I want to migrate this to new hardware and therefore a new windows install.

I have the code working fine when I run it in debug but as soon as I compile (and run as admin which is what I normally do to make sure registry values are retrieved correctly) it seems to get stuck.  CPU usage goes up to 25% which is about double what is normal and the form never loads.

I have gone through the code and started commenting out lines to see what starts to make it work.  Looking at the sub below this code works however if I uncomment any of the commented lines then it fails.  I could understand this if maybe there was a loop or something which it gets stuck in but one of the lines is on;y changing the caption of the form!

As I mentioned earlier I think I have probably compiled projects on hardware and the windows install image 40-50 times never with this problem.  What I don't understand for instance is why the frmlogin.show line is ok when me.show isnt?

The double commented lines are actual comments by the way.

```
Public Sub StartMainForm()
    Dim x As Integer
    
    FirstUpdate = True

'   '  Lees de trek iconen in de imagelist in
'
'    For x = 1 To 15
'        imageListIcon.ListImages.Add x, "Icon" & Format(x, "00"), LoadResPicture(22000 + x, vbResIcon)
'    Next x
'
'   '  Scherm opbouw
'
'    InitAssenControles
'    Form_Resize
'    ClearSelectie
'
'  '  Form_Resize
'    Me.Show
'    Me.WindowState = vbMaximized
'    DataBaseNaam = G.SDataFile
'    Me.Caption = Replace(DataBaseNaam, ".MDB", "")
'
'   '  start Update
'
'    timStatusUpdate.Interval = gUpdateTime
'    timStatusUpdate.Enabled = True

    DoEvents
    gCurrentUser = True
    G.LoginName = "Supervisor"
    G.Auth1 = True
    G.Auth2 = True
    G.Auth3 = True
    G.Auth4 = True
    G.Auth5 = True
    G.Auth6 = True
    G.Auth7 = True
    G.Auth8 = True
    G.Auth9 = True
    G.Auth10 = True

    frmLogin.Show vbModal
    InitAssenControles

    gAssenServer.SetNetwerkKast gNetwerkNummer
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code written in a standard module? `Me` refers to the _current object_, which doesn't exist in a standard module. Looks like that chunk of code was just copy/pasted into here from the form's code-behind. Make sure the top of the module says `Option Explicit`, and [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) could help clean things up here; `x` is declared but not used, and it's not clear what's global state and what's likely module-scoped in the form.

Comment: Unless you _write_ to the registry (e.g. to HKLM), running _As Administrator_ isn't necessary, as typically non-privileged (user) accounts have read access to these parts of the registry. Besides - I had a case where I also experienced crashes in the complied version of the executable, which didn't happen in the IDE. Once I switch the compile option from system/native code to P-code, the problem went away. To this day, I don't know why, which is always an unsatisfying solution. It only happened once with _that_ project though.

Comment: @Hel O'Ween - Your reply hit the nail on the head!  Changing to P-Code worked for me.  No idea why either but thanks!  With the admin rights yeah in other areas of the project we write to the registry hence why we need admin.

@ Matheu Guindon - The is code in the main form and yes it was copied and pasted from there as the project itself is huge.  The code itself is used successfully in hundreds or even thousands of projects so i knew if was the code specifically but something about this instance of it. 

Thanks both for your contributions.